# Is that possible to know micro controller pin voltage and current without using multimeter?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, firmware

So, the condition is there is a Photo Voltic (PV) module connected to a microcontroller (directly to pin 5 and assume that PV module is generating 3V, hypothetically!).

I am wondering if I can some how write a microcontroller firmware or algorithm (may be in c/c++) to know what value of voltage and current I am getting from the small PV module.

Is this possible or I should have to have something in between PV module and controller? I haven't done any physical connection as described but just curious to know.

Comment: If the MCU has a hardware capability of measuring it (which is rarely the case).

Comment: Is there any MCUs like that which provides these kinds of capabilities?

Comment: You better tell us what you are trying to do. Product recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Sounds like you just need an MCU with an ADC?

Comment: I just wondered that if I can implement entire Maximum Power Point Tracking functionalities into an MCU.

Comment: I want to reduce analog parts and want to implement it digitally, if I can!

Comment: Most MCUs now can measure voltage, so that's easy - but not current. Usually you would need a current shunt and a suitable amplifier to get an appropriate voltage, which you can measure with another ADC channel on the MCU.

Comment: @Rajan: Why would you use pin 5 on an unspecified microcontroller? (Hint!)

Comment: @Transistor: I was just pointing at any random pin in general MCU. It has nothing to do with MCU that I am working on. I am currently exploring CC26xx wireless MCU from TI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an MCU, the easiest way it to delegate the measurement task to a dedicated circuit called "charge monitor", with I2C interface. These ICs can be found in section "PMIC-current regulation/management" at say, Digi-Key. An example is the Texas Instruments INA219. There are many similar circuits, from Maxim, etc.

The IC will take care of all analog business, all self-contained, and simple I2C reads will give you Voltage, Current, and even calculated instant Power. All you need is the IC, and a sense resistor (20 - 100 mOhms), depending on desired current range and IC gain grade.

Of course you can do this with a MCU with a built-in ADC, but you will still need a differential current-to-voltage converter, and another ADC channel to measure the voltage itself. Some MSU have differential configuration for ADC channels, which could help to measure the shunt resistor directly.

Comment: @ Ali: Thanks for the answer. I want to replace any possible physical parts in my design and want to replace its (that IC you mentioned) functionality by some code and only want to use in-built MCU functionalities (like ADC)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know whether the PV voltage is high enough to run your MCU, then what you're looking for is an IC called a voltage supervisor. These measure the supply voltage and output a digital signal that toggles when the voltage crosses a threshold. Typically they're used to hold the MCU in reset while the voltage is low. You could probably rig up a controlled shutdown with a few more components.

If you actually want a real voltage and current measurement, you're going to need an ADC. You can divide down the supply voltage with resistors and measure the result. If you have a differential ADC, you can measure the supply current by measuring the voltage across a shunt resistor. If your MCU doesn't have those, you'll need external components. You'll probably need a separate reference voltage to make these reliable. There are ICs for that too.